# what is the best simple way to log output from multiple sub ps scripts calling from a single parent ps script?

Tags: powershell

1.Any good practices and simple way to output a text file as log purpose to log multiple sub ps scripts action e.g. 3-10 parts in a single parent ps script? 
Need to log both parent call to sub ps script and also the log from sub script in case any abnormal things happen.
Is there any piping function like linux sh script that I could append output of each sub script to a log file generate per date 20190423 24 25...

```
#parent scripts

# sub 1
& '.\part1.ps1' # is there anything like writesth.ps1 | log_todayYYYYMMDD.txt ? forgive bringing some pipe concept from sh to ps but is it possible?
# sub 2
& '.\part2.ps1'
...
# sub scripts 10
& '.\part10.ps1'
```

2.how to make a generic log function to keep every where the log with same format?

Please provide some samples if possible. Thanks.

Comment: the easiest seems to be to write to individual files and collect & merge them after the fact. the most flexible way seems to be writing to the event log - you can make a custom one. then let windows handle multiple accesses ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I have been re-using this module file for quite sometime to create log as CSV file, 
You can just save this code as module file, may be "Powershell.Common.Logging.psm1" and then import where you need (in main script)  `Import-Module -Name "$PSScriptRoot\Modules\Powershell.Common.Logging.psm1" -Force`

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script: Common Logging
# Version: 1
# Modified By: Akhilesh Verma;
# Created Date: 1/4/2019
# Comments: Module to enable logging in powershell solution
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$LogDirectoryPath = "$PSScriptRoot\..\Log\"
$global:LogFileName = $null
Set-Variable -Name LogSrc -Value "Main Module Name" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogSrcCommon -Value "COMMON" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogLvlERR -Value "ERROR" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogLvlWRN -Value "WARNING" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogLvlSUC -Value "SUCCESS" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogLvlINF -Value "INFORMATION" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogLvlVRB -Value "VERBOSE" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogOpTRK -Value "TRACK" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogOpRD -Value "READ" -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogOpWT -Value "WRITE" -Scope Global -Force
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Intialize the logging session by creating a new log file
.DESCRIPTION
Create Logfile and capture logging for the given Source  by creating a new log file
.PARAMETER InputPath
-Source $LogSrcReconciliation
.PARAMETER OutputPath
None.
.INPUTS
None. You cannot pipe objects.
.OUTPUTS
None. The function generate a log file in the log folder
.EXAMPLE
Start-Logging -Source $LogSrcReconciliation
#>
function Start-Logging{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Source
)
#ensure log directory exists
if (!(Test-Path $LogDirectoryPath)) {
    New-Item $LogDirectoryPath -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}
$newLogPath = 'Powershell.Log_' + ((Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")) + '.csv'
Set-Variable -Name 'LogFileName' -Value $newLogPath -Scope Global
$LogFilePath = Join-Path $LogDirectoryPath -ChildPath $global:LogFileName
$FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
# Write log entry to $Path
$row = New-Object System.Object # Create an object to append to the array
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date & Time" -Value $FormattedDate
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Source" -Value $Source
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Operation" -Value $LogOpTRK
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Level" -Value $LogLvlVRB
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Reference" -Value 'Start-Logging'
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Message" -Value 'Logging Started.'
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path/URL" -Value $LogFilePath
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Function ID" -Value '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
$row | Export-Csv -Path $LogFilePath -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation
}

<#
.SYNOPSIS
Write Message to host and log file.
.DESCRIPTION
Intialize the logging session by creating a new log file
.PARAMETER InputPath
-Message - Message to log
-Source - Source of the call, Migration/SharePoint/Sharegate
-Level - Logging level, ERROR/WARNING/INFO/SUCCESS.
-Operation - Releated Operation, Read/Write/Track
-Reference - File system Path or SharePoint URL to track log origin
.PARAMETER OutputPath
None.
.INPUTS
None. You cannot pipe objects.
.OUTPUTS
None. The function generate a log file in the specified folder
.EXAMPLE
Write-Log   $ScriptStackTrace -Level 'Error' -Operation 'Read' -Source     $LogSrcMigration
#>
function Write-Log{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Message,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet("ERROR", "WARNING", "SUCCESS", "INFORMATION", "VERBOSE")]
    [string]$Level=$LogLvlINF,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet("TRACK", "WRITE", "READ")]
    [string]$Operation= $LogOpTRK,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$Reference='N/A',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [guid]$FunctionId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$Path = '',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$RemoteLogging = $false
)
Process{
    # Format Date for our Log File
    $FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    # Write message to output and set the $LevelText
    $completeMsg = $FormattedDate + " | " + ("{0, -12}" -f $Level) + ": $Message $Path"
    switch ($Level) {
        $LogLvlERR {
            Write-Host $completeMsg -f Red
        }
        $LogLvlWRN {
            Write-Host $completeMsg -f Cyan
        }
        $LogLvlINF {
            Write-Host $completeMsg -f Yellow
        }
        $LogLvlSUC {
            Write-Host $completeMsg -f Green
        }
        $LogLvlVRB {
            Write-Host $completeMsg -f White
        }
    }
    if($RemoteLogging){
        Send-RemoteLog -Message $Message -Source $Source -Level $Level -Operation $Operation `
         -Reference $Reference -Path $Path -FunctionId $FunctionId
    }
    $LogFilePath = Join-Path $LogDirectoryPath -ChildPath $LogFileName
    # Write log entry to $Path
    $row = New-Object System.Object # Create an object to append to the array
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date & Time" -Value $FormattedDate
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Source" -Value $Source
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Operation" -Value $Operation
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Level" -Value $Level
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Reference" -Value $Reference
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Message" -Value $Message
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path/URL" -Value $Path
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Function ID" -Value $FunctionId
    $row | Export-Csv -Path $LogFilePath -Append
}
}
```

Then you just need to initialize

```
Start-Logging -Source $LogSrc
```

and start logging like -

```
Write-Log "Message you want to log" -Level $LogLvlINF -Operation $LogOpTRK -Path "path related to operation" -Reference $MyInvocation.MyCommand -Source $LogSrc -FunctionId $FunctionId
```

You can also generate a GUID per operation and track the call across functions using FunctionID parameter